# Pond auto top-up project switch failure issues

Tags: switches, relay, load

I am installing a system to top up my pond when the water level drops below a certain level using a solenoid valve.  I decided on 3 float switches - low level switch starts the filling, upper level switch stops the filling, and a 3rd failsafe switch to prevent overfill if something goes wrong.

This is very similar to question 74155, for a boat bilge system (just in reverse).  And the circuit I came up with is more or less the same:

[image]

The issue I have is that 2 of the 3 switches have immediately gone bad (permanently closed). It could be bad switches to start with, although I did test that they switched before powering up.  So I am thinking that I overloaded them.  At which point I am out of my depth (if I wasn't already with the project design!).

I am using 24vdc.  I didn't want 240VAC near water and I thought the wire runs were going to be quite long, so 24vdc would be better than 12vdc (in practice 12vdc would have been fine).

I haven't been able to accurately establish the power consumption of the solenoid valve.  I thought it was 18W, but it could be 40-50W.  I am using a simple plug-in PSU and I initially tried one rated at 0.75A but this would not maintain the opening of the valve.  I have switched to a 3A one and that is fine.

The relay (HLR24) is rated for 8A at 30VDC.  But the switches are rated for a max switching current of 0.5A and a max carry current of 1.0A (which seems typical for float switches).  Is this where I have gone wrong?  How should I design the circuit to cope with this?  Or have I just been unlucky?

BTW, it is the upper and lower float switches that have gone bad, the overflow switch is OK and will operate the solenoid valve.  When I look at my circuit design I can see that I have the load flowing through this switch so I find it odd that this is the one that is still OK!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please update your question with the part numbers and data sheets for the solenoid and switches. BTW the circuit looks functional, so the knowledge of the parts id important.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This is the info I have...

Solenoid Valve
- Operating Type: Directly Driven
- State: Normally Closed
- Supply Voltage: DC 12V / DC 24V
- Supply Current: 0.12A
- Withstand voltage: 1.0Mpa
- Working Temperature: -5℃ ~ 80℃
- Pressure Range: 0~0.7Mpa; Water 0~0.5Mpa; Oil 0~0.5Mpa
- Fluid Viscosity: Under 20CST
- Installation: the direction of the water flow is indicated on the valve body
- Valve Body: Zinc Alloy, Full Copper Coil
- Oil Seal Material: NBR
- Pipe Size: 1/2", DN15
- Flow Diameter: 16mm
- Dimension: 118x85x65mm/4.65x3.35x2.56 inch

Comment: Float switches:
Material: Stainless Steel SUS
Cable Length:About 30cm
Working Temperature:-30℃~+125℃
Color:Silver Tone
Body Material:SUS304
1x Stainless Steel Vertical Water Level Switch
Max Contact Rating: 10W/SPST
Max Switching Current: 0.5A
Max Carry Current: 1A
Max Switching Voltage: 100VDC
Max Breakdown Voltage: 220V DC
Max Contact Resistance: 100mΩ

Comment: I haven't added any fuse protection in the circuit.  The PSU claims protection for over voltage/current & short circuit, but should I am guessing I should have used fuses as well.
Also I think I should move the position of the overflow switch so it is not carrying the load.